# unable to install Ubuntu 13.04 on hcl me

Tags: system-installation

While installing Ubuntu 13.04 on my hcl laptop. I am getting error which is "gpu lookup failed". I have tried everything possible. please help me.
thank you.
Let me explain my full problem. after booting when the start screen comes with Ubuntu logo and some dots flashing .after that instead of showing the option to try or install ,there comes the background screen which is also not with proper background but has some distorted marking on it. and after that it remain like this while the cursor can be moved freely .after 3or5 minute it hangs there and then the black screen comes with message on top saying gpu lookup failed ,and it tries again saying starting again it repeats saying that gpu lookup failed. one more thing my laptop is of year 2007 and there is one update for it also in 2010 but I have not updated my bios . could it be the cause.

Comment: Do you have a dedicated graphics card?

Comment: yes it is nvidea's 512 mb graphics card

Comment: Have you tried this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it ?

Comment: But in that thing there is no mention gpu look up

Comment: It might be related to the graphics card, so disabling it while installing can confirm whether the issue is related?

Comment: Let me explain my full problem. after booting when the start screen comes with ubunto logo and some dots flashing .after that instead of showing the option to try or install ,there comes the background screen which is also not with proper background but has some distorted marking on it. and after that it remain like this while the cursur canbe moved freely .

Comment: I recommend you try the link posted and update the question with your last comment.

Comment: after 3or5 minute it hangs there and then the black screen comes with message on top saying gpu lookup failed ,and it tries again saying starting again it repeats saying that gpu lookup failed. one more thing my laptop is of year 2007 and there is one update for it also in 2010 but I have not updated my bios . could it be the cause.

Comment: Plsss. tell me how to disable graphics card while installing ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the case that you graphics card drivers are missing or a related issue. To disable your graphics card while installing, insert your bootable disk and restart your machine and boot from the bootable device.

The following part is referred from [My computer boots to black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

- When you see this:

  [image: boot screen]

press <kbd>F6</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and select English:

[image: options]

- Press F6, use the arrow keys to go down to `nomodeset`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. An *x* will appear to its left. Then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to "Try Ubuntu without installing."

  [image: choose options]

You can also try `acpi = off` and `nolapic` if `nomodset` also shows up as a black screen.

Comment: Then after that how to enable graphics card again.

Comment: You need to download drivers for Nvidia, refer to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers